# Making functions within a class DRY in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP and have created a class as follows:

```
class ApiController extends AppController {
    // functions
}
```

I have about 10 functions in the class and I have found that I have repeated myself with the exact 3 same lines of code at the beginning of every function:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $data = $this->request->input('json_decode',true);
    $authUser = explode('.',$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $location_id = $authUser[1];
    // Rest of my function
}
```

Is there any way that I can create something in the class which runs those 3 lines of code first, and then makes the $data and $location_id variables available for my functions to use, or must I write those 3 lines for every function?

Comment: Why not add that initialization to constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using private method.

```
private $data = null;
private $locationId = null;
public function __construct($request = null, $response = null) {
    parent::__construct($request = null, $response = null);
    $this->data = $this->request->input('json_decode',true);
    $authUser = explode('.',$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $this->locationId = $authUser[1];
}
```

and then use it like this

```
$this->locationId;
```

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Because we don't know if this data is needed in all methods.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky `At the beginning of every (of this 10) function`. He can also got 20 methods there and use it only in 10.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Maybe you just don't understand `controller` idea, or just want to talk to somebody. For one request, only one method is called. So there is no optimalization, only code refactorization.

Comment: To clarify, I have 10 methods in my class and I need json_decode to be called for all of them.

Comment: @Joseph So using constructor makes sense. Updated answer.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky You were right here, but it doesn't mean that your argument was right. Just lucky.

Comment: @ElonThan The first thing you posted (the private method) worked, but then I replaced it with the constructor and I get `Call to a member function input() on a non-object`

Comment: @Joseph Are you sure that you added `parent::__construct()` in the first line of constructor?

Comment: @ElonThan Yes, `parent::__construct()` is definitely in there.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. I have to do `public function __construct($request = null, $response = null) {
            parent::__construct($request, $response);`

Comment: I guess this is something specific to the framework (CakePHP) I'm using. Do you think so? Anyway, I've marked your answer as correct now.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method and put the 2 variables as a property of the class.

e.g.

```
class ApiController {
    private $location_id;
    private $data;

    private function init() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then access the variables by doing `$this->location_id`.

Comment: Why not add that initialization to constructor?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky It depends on whether he wants to do it.

Comment: How it depends on that? and how this one is better than that?